# When is $(dy/dx)^{-1}=dx/dy$ for multivariable functions?

Tags: derivatives, calculus

In general for a multivariable functions $y(m,n)$, $x(m,n)$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial m}\frac{dm}{dx}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial n}\frac{dn}{dx}\tag{1}$$
and
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial m}\frac{dm}{dy}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial n}\frac{dn}{dy}\tag{2}$$

so in general clearly $(dy/dx)^{-1}$ **need not be equal** to $dx/dy$.

My question is what is the precision Mathematical conditions on functions $y(m,n)$ and $x(m,n)$ under which this equality holds.

Clearly I could explicitly calculate $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ and check the equality, but is there a better way to see this equality from the point of view of the properties of the functions. Here, by functions I mean functions that commonly appear in physics (and definitely not some exotic function that has no physical origins - this is the reason I decided to post it in PhysicsSE and not MathSE).

If there exist any such properties, I would also like to have a mathematical proof that states that these properties are equivalent to proving the equality explicitly from the first principle i.e. using (1) and (2).

---

**Edit:** I have been notified of a possible ill definition of these particular chain rules, which would mean the question itself is invalid and I very likely might have misinterpreted something. To **verify this possible ill definition** I have posed a question in [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057451/validity-of-this-particular-chain-rule).

Comment: Could you provide an example of when we "take this equality for granted"?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Mathematics is probably not the right place because they tend to disdain expressions like $dy / dx = (dx/dy)^{-1}$.

Comment: @NiharKarve - I couldn't come up with an example (I am pretty sure that I have come across this multiple times earlier, I just remembered this issue now (when I saw a very simple chain rule that has nothing to do with this)). I will try to find an example and edit the post soon. That was exactly my reason to post this here and not in MathsSE, because the first thing math people would ask is an example. Here I am hoping that some physics might have some across something like this and can relate to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its only true when $y$ is a single variable function of $x$, so
$$
y = y(x).
$$
If $y$ is a function of multiple variables, say $y = y(m,n)$, then its derivative is really a vector.
$$
\nabla y = \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial m}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial n}\right).
$$
Furthermore, the derivative of $x$ is also a vector, $\nabla x$.

Now, note that you can't even divide vectors even if you wanted to. In general, the expression
$$
\frac{\nabla y}{\nabla x}
$$
just makes no sense. So then, in the multivariable case, the expression
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
likewise makes no sense in general.

However, there is a special case in which it does make sense. That is when $y$ really can be written as a function of $x$, i.e.
$$
y(m,n) = f( x(m, n) )
$$
for some single variable function $f$. In this special case, $\nabla y$ is actually parallel to $\nabla x$, so it sort of does make sense to take the quotient $\nabla y / \nabla x$. And also, because $y = f(x)$, $y$ really is in a way just a single variable function of $x$, and so your identity will hold only in this case.

Also, as written now, your equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are simply incorrect. $m$ and $n$ are not functions of $x$, so the expression $\partial m / \partial x$ doesn't make much sense. It's an incorrect application of the chain rule. Therefore you won't be able to prove anything from those starting points. To reiterate, the expression $dy/dx$ just has no meaning when $y$ and $x$ are general functions of $m$ and $n$, simply because a value of $x$ does not determine a unique value of $y$.

**Edit:**
As for your equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, here is the "meaning" of those equations. Each pair of functions of two variables defines a Jacobian which is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. So for the functions $(y(m,n), x(m,n))$ we have the Jacobian
$$
J_{x(m,n), y(m,n)} = \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial m} & \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial n} \\ \tfrac{\partial y}{\partial m} & \tfrac{\partial y}{\partial n} \end{pmatrix}
$$
and for the functions $(m(x,y), n(x,y))$ we have the Jacobian
$$
J_{m(x,y), n(x,y)} = \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{\partial m}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial m}{\partial y} \\ \tfrac{\partial n}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial n}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because the maps here are inverse functions, one can prove that $J_{x(m,n), y(m,n)} J_{m(x,y), n(x,y)}= I$.

If we want to calculate the Jacobian for the composition of the two maps, which is $(x(m(x,y), n(x,y)), y(m(x,y), n(x,y) )$, the correct formula to use is to multiply the two Jacobians together. However, this is just $I$, which tautologically confirms that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial y} \\ \tfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial y}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
However, you won't be able to draw any conclusions about the form of $x$ or $y$ from this calculation. All you can do is calculate the identity matrix tautologically.

Comment: Ohh Okay... But I am not taking a gradient here. The equations are something like $\grad_{m,n}y.\grad_{x,y}m$ (not exatly though - my equations are scalar equations and not vectors, so its like a grad dotted with another grad or something ig). And regarding your last para, why not? m, n can be rewritten as m(x,y) , n(x,y) . Yes provided they are bijective mapping ig. But in "physics" I think the bijection part is satisfied, is'nt it?. Probably I should post a slight variant of this in Maths SE too. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: While you can also parameterize $m$ and $n$ with $x$ and $y$, for example as $m = m(x,y)$ and $n = n(x,y)$, then the full dependence of $y$ becomes $y = y(m(x,y), n(x,y) )$, which is a pretty suspicious equation because $y$ is getting defined in terms of itself. The main point though is that $dy/dx$ has no meaning unless $y$ is a function of $x$, and this is a very special condition if $y$ and $x$ are both functions of two variables.

Comment: Please see my last edit for the meaning of the chain rule in this situation.

Comment: I will go through the Jacobian in some time, I am slightly busy now. So what you claim is $dy/dx=0$, but just think of this set of function $y=m+n$ and $x=m+n$, here $y=x$ and the conclusion would be $dy/dx=1$. Is that a contradiction?

Comment: In that case you can not invert the functional dependence, i.e. it is simply impossible to write $m$ and $n$ as functions of $x$ and $y$, so if they functions $m(x,y)$ and $n(x,y)$ have no meaning then expressions like $\partial m / \partial x$ certainly have no meaning. Furthermore, the determinant of the Jacobian of that map is 0: the two rows are linearly independent, and it can't be inverted anyway.

Comment: I perfectly agree with your answer and the Jacobian proof. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You're allowed to do this when you're working with functions of a single variable.

If you check, you'll find that in all examples in physics where $dy / dx = (dx / dy)^{-1}$ is used, this is the case. Examples include the trajectory of a single particle, which can be parametrized as $x(t)$, and the potential in a problem with spherical symmetry, which can be parametrized as $V(r)$.

Comment: I agree. But what about multivariable functions? Do you think my chain rule is wrong (which is what apparently many people are thinking - although I cant see a reason for that) or are you of the opinion that there doesn't exist any simpler way of showing the equality.

Answer (score 2):

As @knzhou has noted, in case of a function of a single variable
$$
\left[y'(x)\right]^{-1} = \frac{dx}{dy},
$$
since the *derivative* and the *differential* of a function of a single variable [are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597042/765359).

This is not the case for the functions of several variables, see, e.g., my answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565329/247642) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549345/247642).

Comment: I totally agree with this for single variable functions. I am thinking of its validity for multivariable functions. Thank I should probably change the heading!

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy as I stated in my answer: it is not true in case of multivariable functions. And I disagree with the claim that *physicists take it for granted* - in fact, in some fields (such as thermodynamics) special care is taken to keep other variables constant whiel one is varied when deriving mathematical relations.

Comment: For multivariable functions it is true only when we fix the differentiation direction - effectively making it into a function of one variable.

Comment: I agree that that direction has to be fixed (partial derivative). But regarding my OP, do you mean to say that my chain rules are wrong or that a simpler way of showing the equality of reciprocals doesn't exist? I should probably remove the granted part since I am unable to find an eg as of now, I will add that statement back if I can find one.

Comment: In your case $y$ is not even a unique function of $x$, so the derivatives $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ might not even exist.

Comment: I agree if you say there exist "some fun $y$" for which $y$ is not a unique fun of $x$. But I don't agree if you say this is true for "all funs of $y$" Here is an eg - $y=m+n$ and $x=m+n$ clearly $y=x$ is very unique. Here, by Physics functions I mean functions like the eg I just gave.

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy Your function $y$ is an implicit function of $x$: $y=y(n(x),m(x))$. If it is invertible, it is a function fo one variable. If it is not invertible, you have no right to write your second relation.

Comment: So are you saying that if I guarantee bijection between  x, y and m, n (as in the principle of parametrisation) then both eq (1) and (2) are valid?

Comment: If you guarantee that both $y(x)$ and $x(y)$ are unique/unambiguous functions.

Comment: Ha okay I too agree on that, especially because I didn't get an opposition in MathSE as of now. Do you have any thoughts on whether the equality of reciprocals is valid or not? If its valid, which it probably is, when what is the conditions on the functions when we can directly use the equality without going through explicitly checking it using eq(1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be obvious but you haven't specified all the information yet. Excuse me for changing your notation but define
\begin{align}
x(\vec u):\quad \mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R\\
y(\vec u):\quad \mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R
\end{align}
where I redefined $(m,n)$ as an n-dimensional point $\vec u$. Right now when I try to calculate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ I will get stuck because I'm missing information. You are differentiating $y(x)=y(\vec u(x))$ with respect to $x$ but we have never specified $\vec u(x)$. We can't just invert $x(\vec u)\rightarrow\vec u(x)$ because for a given value $x$ there's an infinite number of points $\vec u$ that give the same value $x$. To define a total derivative you implicitly have to specify a path in $\mathbb R^n$ because by definition a total derivative only depends on one variable. Once I have specified $\vec u(x)$ it is obvious that $dy/dx=(dx/dy)^{-1}$ because $y(\vec u(x))$ is just a function of one variable i.e. you can write it as $y(x)$. If $y(x)$ is invertible then
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy}y(x(y))&=\frac{dy(x(y))}{dx}\frac{dx(y)}{dy}\\
&=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}\overset !=1
\end{align}
So the mathematical conditions would be that $x(\vec u),\vec u(x),y(\vec u),\vec u(y)$ all exist and are continuous. I don't know much about function analysis so maybe there are better conditions.